# Error handling in GameState Machine for menus using Singleton Style classes

Tags: c++, state, state-machine

Let me preface by saying I am very new to programming and c++. I have been researching various methods for creating a menu system for a simple game that allows the player to go from one menu(representing a location) to the next and back to create a menu-driven world to explore with many locations each with their own menu chains to dive into. The problem I am having is, I intend to expand this to possibly hundreds of locations as I tell a story, so I want to avoid using endless if else and switch statement chains. I have been trying to find a solution that is simple, maintainable, and easily expandable. This is when I stumbled upon the existence of State Machines. I understand to some extent the push pop of a stack, but actually implementing this in code with my still budding understanding is far from trivial for me and after about 2 weeks of trial and error with each iteration ending up in a bundle of errors that I am ill equipped to troubleshoot, I must resign to asking the community for guidance. This is imperative to get this little game to work and I refuse to give up on it yet.

In its current state, I am having the following seemingly simple errors, but with every solution I try to correct them, it only seems to add to the number. These specific errors are less of the issue and more a question of how can I turn what I have into the foundation for a working state machine, or should I scrap it and start again?

- several 'identifiers not found'
- several 'cannot instantiate abstract class'
- 'C2664 'void StateMachine::pushState(State *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'TownState' to 'State *'
- several Messages stating nothing more than 'due to the following members'
- several missing user defined conversion operators.

On their own, many of these issues I am confident I can resolve in a simpler codebase, but whenever I fix one, I end up with many more different errors seemingly unrelated. At one point I was up to 200 errors. I have reverted the code back to the least amount of errors I could just to ask this question, and to basically start over, and any push in the right direction here from an experienced developer would be much appreciated. Even if it is only resources to read to get a better understanding of how all this should come together or strategies one should use to approach this kind of design.

I feel there is a really simple refactor and a few minor touch ups hidden in here somewhere and it will work fine. I'm just not seeing it with my still budding grasp on coding. I have tried too many major and minor changes over the last two weeks to the point of frustration, along with complete redos. I have been reading articles, browsing stack overflows questions and watching videos but am unable to find resources that tread close enough to this specific project's needs or that are simple enough for my noob self to fully understand and implement.

Here is the entirety of my code below. If this is not appropriate or there is a better way to ask this question to make this more clear for Stack Overflow's expectations, let me know and I will amend it. Thank you all.

(P.S. I have not yet split many of the files into .h and .cpp yet. In these cases, I have omitted the .cpp files.

main.cpp

```
#include "state_handling.h"
#include "state_machine.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "main_menu.h"
#include "options_state.h"
#include "town_darda.h"
#include "the_valley.h"
#include "quit_state.h"


// Note: to return to previous State, use "stateMachine.pop_state();" as the case option.

class GamePlayState : public State {
public:
    GamePlayState() {}
    void handleInput() {}; //handle input specific to Game Play.
    void update() {}; //update logic specific to Game Play.
    void renderMenu() {}; //render logic and menu specific to Game Play.
};

int main() {
    Game game;
    game.run();

    return 0;
}
```

state_machine.h

```
#ifndef _STATE_MACHINE_H
#define _STATE_MACHINE_H

#include <vector>
#include "state_handling.h"

//Manages current Game State Stack.
class StateMachine {
private:
    std::vector<State*> states;
public:
    void pushState(State* state) {
        states.push_back(state);
    }
    void popState() {
        states.pop_back();
    }
    State* currentState() {
        return states.back();
    }
    bool isEmpty() {
        return states.empty();
    }
};

#endif
```

state_handling.cpp

```
#include "state_handling.h"

class GameState : public State {
public:
    void handleInput() override {
        // Handle input specific to the GameState
    }

    void update() override {
        // Update game logic specific to the GameState
    }

    void renderMenu() override {

    };

};
```

state_handling.h

```
#ifndef _STATE_HANDLING_H
#define _STATE_HANDLING_H

class State {
public:
    virtual void handleInput() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void renderMenu() = 0;

private:
    static State* m_instance;
};

#endif
```

game.h

```
#ifndef _GAME_H
#define _GAME_H

#include "state_machine.h"
#include "main_menu.h"

//Responsible for creating and managing the state machine. All other classes that need to use it can access it through the 'Game' instance.
class Game {
private:
    StateMachine stateMachine;
public:
    void run() {
        stateMachine.pushState(new MainMenuState());
        while (!stateMachine.isEmpty()) {
            stateMachine.currentState()->handleInput();
            stateMachine.currentState()->update();
            stateMachine.currentState()->renderMenu();
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

main_menu.h

```
#ifndef _MAIN_MENU_H
#define _MAIN_MENU_H

#include "state_machine.h"
#include "town_darda.h"
#include <iostream>

class MainMenuState : public State {
public:
    MainMenuState() {}
    void handleInput() {
        //handle input specific to Main Menu.
        int choice;
        std::cout << "MAIN MENU:\n[1] Start Game\n[2] Options\n[3]Quit\n" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            //Introduction here before entering game first time.
            stateMachine.pushState(DardaState());
            break;
        case 2:
            //stateMachine.pushState(OptionsState());
            break;
        case 3:
            //stateMachine.pushState(QuitState());
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid Option...";
            break;
        }
    }
    void update() {}; //update logic specific to Main Menu.
    void renderMenu() {}; //render logic and menu specific to Main Menu.
};

#endif
```

the_valley.h

```
#ifndef _THE_VALLEY_H
#define _THE_VALLEY_H

#include <iostream>
#include "state_handling.h"
#include "gamestates.h"
#include "state_machine.h"
#include "game.h"


class TheValleyState : public State {
public:
    TheValleyState() {}
    void handleInput() {
        int choice{};
        std::cout << "THE VALLEY MENU:\n[1] Explore\n[2] Hunt\n[3] Information\n[4]Leave Area\n[X]Options" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            //stateMachine.pushState(TheValleyExplore());
            break;
        case 2:
            //stateMachine.pushState(TheValleyHunt());
            break;
        case 3:
            //stateMachine.pushState(TheValleyInfo());
            break;
        case 4:
            //Display The Valley's Adjacent Area Menus (Darda, Coral Cove, Bluster Bluffs, Thalen Pass)  
            //Handle choice then go to new location state "stateMachine.pushState(XXXXXXState());"
            stateMachine.pushState(DardaState());
            break;
        case 5:
            //change choice to char and allow for X to open Options Menu.
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid Option...";
            break;
        }
    }
    void update() {}
    void renderMenu() {}
};

#endif
```

town_darda.h

```
#ifndef _TOWN_DARDA_H
#define _TOWN_DARDA_H

#include <iostream>
#include "state_handling.h"
#include "state_machine.h"
#include "the_valley.h"

class DardaState : public State {
public:
    static DardaState* instance() {
        if (!m_instance)
            m_instance = new DardaState();
        return m_instance;
    }
    void handleInput() {
        int choice{};
        std::cout << "DARDA MENU:\n[1] Market\n[2] Inn\n[3]Leave Town\n" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            //stateMachine.pushState(DardaMarket());
            break;
        case 2:
            //stateMachine.pushState(DardaInn());
            break;
        case 3:
            stateMachine.pushState(TheValleyState());
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid Option...";
            break;
        }
    }
    void update() {}
    void renderMenu() {}

private: 
    static DardaState* m_instance;
};

#endif
```

quit_state.h

```
#ifndef _QUIT_STATE_H
#define _QUIT_STATE_H
#include "state_handling.h"

class QuitState : public State {
public:
    QuitState() {}
    void handleInput() {}; //handle input specific to Quit State.
    void update() {}; //update logic specific to Quit State.
    void renderMenu() {}; //render logic and menu specific to Quit State.
};

#endif
```

options_state.h

```
#ifndef _OPTIONS_STATE_H
#define _OPTIONS_STATE_H
#include "state_handling.h"

class OptionState : public State {
public:
    OptionState() {}
    void handleInput() {}; //handle input specific to Option State.
    void update() {}; //update logic specific to Option State.
    void renderMenu() {}; //render logic and menu specific to Option State.
};

#endif
```

Comment: This function `void pushState(State* state)` accepts a pointer argument. In this statement `stateMachine.pushState(DardaState());` you are trying to pass an instance of an object, not a pointer to one. I didn't look for any other issues, it's just too much code. I would suggest starting much smaller and focusing on a single issue. In the end though this approach will likely me unmaintainable. You should consider a more data driven design.

Comment: Much appreciated! I will check out some data driven approaches. And apologies for the length of the code. I just wanted to provide as much as I could in hopes people could understand the mess I created. haha.  Cheers!

Comment: *"At one point I was up to 200 errors"* If you haven't, you should have *started* with a minimal amount of code which compiles and run *without* any warnings or error (an Hello World would be perfect), then add *one* piece of functionality at a time, *test* it, correct *any* warnings and errors and only then add another piece. Also, consider reading: https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Comment: Haha yeah it always starts small.  But it inevitably must grow.  But thank you for the link.  I'll check it out.